# History tracking on Campaing member Object, Or any other form of tracking

Tags: workflow, process-builder, custom-field, fields

Is there any way to have a custom field that will contain a date and time a different custom field in the same object is changed ? 
It is on a campaign Member Object where the "History Tracking" button is missing.

I've tried using the process builder and workflows and flows but nothing worked.

Thank you for answers

/////////////////EDIT////////////////
I've added screenshots of What I've done so far:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can track changes in certain fields via "Set History Tracking" button in an object's Fields page, in setup. Check if that works for you.

Comment: i doesn't seem to be an option in the campaign Members object.

Comment: Ok, I don't really use workflows and process builders so I don't know if they are capable of achieving this, but you can create an "before update" trigger and add some code to check if your desired tracked field has changed and store that information in another field.

Comment: when that process is fired ? when record is created or edited? did you activate the process?

Comment: Its fired when its created and edited, yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

salesforce has powerful standard configurable feature [Field History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?siteLang=en_us&id=tracking_field_history.htm&type=0)

Just enable it for sobject and for field and you will be able to track field changes by means of UI and API

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on the Campain member object, The option is missing.